How can I solve "warning: comparison between pointer and integer"
I was trying to make a program that reallocates memory from 1B to 100B with the following program.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char* p = malloc(sizeof(char));
    printf("%p\n", p);

    for (int i=2;i<100;i++) {
        char* q = realloc(p, i);
        printf("%p\n", q);
        if (!q==(char*)NULL) {
            p = q;
            printf("%p %dB\n", p, i);
        } else {
            printf("error\n");
        }
    }
    free(p);
}

When I compile this code, an error "warning: comparison between pointer and integer" occurs in if (!q==(char*)(NULL)).
I tried to use normal NULL and casted it into the type of char*, but neither of them worked. It works perfectly if I replace char* q = realloc(p, i); to p = realloc(p, i);.

! binds more tightly than == so that comparison is (!q) == NULL. Try != instead...

No need to cast NULL. And as mentioned above ! has precedence. You need if (q != NULL). demo.

Unrelated to the question, but fprintf(stderr, "Descriptive error msg\n");  Spread the word! Errors belong on the error stream!

I understand. Thank you for the answers!!

In this case, fprintf(stderr, "allocation of %u bytes failed: %s\n", i, strerror(errno)).  When a system-level operation fails, always print strerror(errno) and the values of relevant arguments, in this case the size of the allocation.  (You'll need string.h and errno.h.) (Printing strerror(errno) is less important for malloc failure than for other system operations; it's almost always going to come out "Virtual memory exhausted" which doesn't really add information.  But it's a crucial habit to maintain.)

Your issue is a warning and not an error, but is nevertheless important to solve.
The problem is that ! has precedence over ==, and so the expression:
!q==(char*)NULL

Is actually:
(!q)==(char*)NULL

You could solve it by adding () around the equality check, but the simplest solution is to use operator != instead.
Also there is no need to cast NULL.
So your relevant if should become:
if (q != NULL) {

Live demo
